# React Router v4 :param conflicting with 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around react router. At the moment I'm trying to accomplish a router that looks something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route exact path="/:pageName" component={Page} />
            <Route component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The idea is that the Page component will use the :pageName to render the correct title and content. However, if the pageName doesn't exist, it should render the notFound (404) page.

At the moment the 404 page will never render, as all urls matches the Page route.

What is the conventional way to check if the pageName exist, and only match the Page component in cases where it does? should I set up the 's dynamically, or should the Page component check and redirect? How should I think about this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you would like that parameter pageName lies within certain set of predefined values, I would just list each of those values as separate route:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route exact path="/page1" component={Page} />
            <Route exact path="/page2" component={Page} />
            <Route exact path="/pagexyz" component={Page} />
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If you insist to have just one route for all pages, according to this article [you can use regexp to specify path](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-regular-expressions-with-routes-with-react-router-v4) so ou can write regexp that will accept only page names you will have and reject others.

If set of existing pages is not predefined but contained in array I would use map to generate routes like in:

```
pageNames.map((name) => (<Route exact path={'/'+name} component={Page} />
```

Comment: But how do you then access the :pageName parameter in the Page component?

Comment: you still get match property from which you can take path or url. You may need to remove a character or two from it. Or even better, you can make Page1 , Page2, .. etc components that are derived from Page, and use those components in routers

Comment: If you find my answer not clear enough, please help me how could I make it more clear. If you know of better way, please provide it as an new answer.